# Is there any direct way to do what pin_ptr does?

Tags: c++-cli

Can the behaviour of pin_ptr be achieved directly in C++/CLI? For example, is it possible to write CLR code directly, something like `asm` for native apps?

An example of what I would like to do is a wrapper for a `pin_ptr` (impossible because of the restrictions on `pin_ptr`s).

```
class WrappedPtr
{
public:
    explicit WrappedPtr(String^ s)
    {
        pin = PtrToStringChars(s);
        // I want to pin s for the lifetime of this object (only used on the stack)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [GCHandle.Alloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1246yz8f.aspx). with [GCHandleType.Pinned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y4ak54.aspx). You can then use [GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.addrofpinnedobject.aspx) to get the address of the .NET object.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go when I get a chance.